# VSCode says there's an error while activating IntelliCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am having this problem everytime I start VS code. It says , "Sorry, something went wrong activating IntelliCode support for Python. Please check the "Python" and "VS IntelliCode" output windows for details." Help me...

Python Output

```
2023-04-22 19:18:22.567 [error] sendStartupTelemetry() failed. [s [Error]: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
    at Object.dispose (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:1996337)
    at Object.dispose (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:2048110)
    at S.handleConnectionClosed (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:2048388)
    at S.handleConnectionClosed (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:2203069)
    at c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:2048198
    at i.invoke (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:1998050)
    at o.fire (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:1998815)
    at Z (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:1984693)
    at i.invoke (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:1998050)
    at o.fire (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:1998815)
    at p.fireClose (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:2006635)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.7.11111009\out\client\extension.js:2:2017629)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)] {
  code: -32097,
  data: undefined
}
```

VSCode IntelliCode Output

```
Error while activating Python: {"name":"Error","message":"Activating extension 'ms-python.vscode-pylance' failed: Cannot find module 'c:\\Users\\bhava\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.4.30\\dist\\extension.bundle.js'\n
Require stack:\n- 
e:\\coffee\\resources\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\vs\\loader.js\n- e:\\coffee\\resources\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\bootstrap-amd.js\n- e:\\coffee\\resources\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\bootstrap-fork.js\n- ."}
```

It used to work fine but it suddenly started showing this. What should I do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: your installation of the python extension might be broken. Try uninstalling the python extension and reinstalling it. If that doesn't work, try deleting `c:\Users\bhava\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.4.30` and then uninstalling the python extension and reinstalling it. Let me know if either of those works, and if so, which one.